# Is there a way to ignore Float Inexact result

Tags: exception, vb6

I am working with a very old vb6 application.

I have made a windows update.
Since this update, i got an exception in my vb6 application:

```
Float inexact Result occurred in "kernelbase.dll"
```

I suppose kernelbase.dll now checks invalid float results and i suppose the previous version of kernelbase.dll did not made those tests.

Is there a way to disable those checks in windows kernel ?
I do not have the vb6 application source code...

Comment: I think you should use a VB tag, rather than "windows-kernel".

Comment: You might look into whether the App Compatibility Toolkit can provide a shim that will make Windows support your app's behavior.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It is entirely normal.  Nothing to do with floating point, it is just an exception type that the vb6 runtime hijacked to implement its own error handling.  Use On Error to handle errors.  Or perhaps more appropriate, remove it so that errors don't get swallowed without any diagnostic.